# Angular: How do I return all data for selected item in mat-select on mat-dialog whilst keeping code for selected default value

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a modal mat-dialog populating a mat-select. The dropdown is populated with languages. I'm binding the (value) to the ID of the language so it can be preselected with a default value if data is passed into the dialog. However, I would like to bring back the "ID" and the "language description" seen in the dropdown. Is there a way to populate both data fields when returning the data of a mat-select on mat-dialog-close? I do understand why I am getting "data.ID" and "data.translation" back, but how can I get the "data.language" selected populated? Important: dropdown is pre-selected with data.id when a language has previously been selected, so do not want to lose default value functionality unless there is another way.

Thank you in advance.

.html

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="fullwidth">
    <p>Select language to translate</p>
    <mat-form-field class="fullwidth">      
            <mat-label>Language</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(value)]="data.id">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let langItem of languageList$;" [value]="langItem.value">            
                    {{langItem.description}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    
    <mat-form-field class="fullwidth">          
        <mat-label>Enter translation here</mat-label>
        <textarea class="textarea" matInput placeholder="Ex. Translation here..." [(ngModel)]="data.translation"></textarea>    
    </mat-form-field>

</div> <div mat-dialog-actions>   <button mat-stroked-button class="right" [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>Save</button>  </div>
```

.ts

```
    openTranslationDialog(event, elem): void {
        const dialogRef = this.translateDialog.open(TranslationModalComponent, {
          
          data: {id: String(this._transData?.id), language: this._transData?.language, translation: this._transData?.translation}
        });
        
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {   
          console.log("Language Description: " + result.description);
          console.log("Language ID: " + result.id);  //only get ID back

});
}
```

json

```
{code: "1033", description: "Afrikaans", value: "100000001"}
{code: "1033", description: "Damara", value: "100000002"}
{code: "1033", description: "English", value: "100000000"}
{code: "1033", description: "German", value: "100000003"}
{code: "1033", description: "isiNdebele", value: "100000004"}
{code: "1033", description: "isiXhosa", value: "100000005"}
{code: "1033", description: "isiZulu", value: "100000006"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's in the `[mat-dialog-close]` where you indicate what value do you want to received in the "result" when subscribe. So you can create a function in your TranslationModalComponent

```
getData() {
    const language = this.languageList$.find(
      x => x.value == (this.data as any).id
    );
    return { ...this.data, ...language };
  }
```

And use

```
<button [mat-dialog-close]="getData()" ...>Save</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, your a star, worked like a charm. So obvious now. 
1 thing I did notice was that I had to do some validation before doing the "find". I was getting exceptions when the dialog loads due to it running this method and the "languageList" or selected "Id" were not populated yet. How do you prevent the event from triggering all the time? Perhaps this is for another thread or is the answer simple?

Answer (score 0):

Final piece of code that worked, thanks to @Eliseo

```
getData() {
  if ((this.languageService.languageList.length > 0) && ((this.data as any).id > 0))
  {    
    const language = this.languageList.find(
    x => x.value == (this.data as any).id
  );  
    if (language)
      return { id: language.value, language: language.description, translation: this.data.translation};
    else
      return { id: "", language: "", translation: ""};
  }  
}
```